# Reactjs, render() is executed after redirect

Tags: reactjs, redirect, render

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (sessionStorage.loggedInUser === undefined && localStorage.loggedInUser === undefined) {
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }
    //Check if user owns the car to see if we should send the ajax

    ajax.request.get("/cars/all").then((allCars) => {

        this.setState({
            allCars: allCars
        })
    })

}

componentWillMount() {
    if (sessionStorage.loggedInUser === undefined && localStorage.loggedInUser === undefined) {
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }
}
```

I have this methods, i see by the debugging that the code is passing trough them, but after the redirect it goes to the render method and start executing it. Why?

Comment: you are expecting the page which consist of componentDidMount be removed since you are redirecting yet it still rendering in the background, is this what you meant ?

Comment: yes, it still executed the render method, and i get undefined exception

Comment: as far as I can understand "push" doesn't remove the old page, "replace" does

Comment: which is why you it still rendering in the background because you run ajax call and "setState" is executed which in the end will trigger the render method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've begun the process of mounting a component, it's lifecycle methods are in the queue.  Behind the scenes, react is running these methods to generate the "virtual dom".  Even if the results never quite reach the user, they still need to be executed for reacts internal purposes.

From the looks of things though, it seems what you want is a way to interrupt a react-router page transition and redirect the user to the index page.  That's definitely possible, but the `componentDidMount` hook is not the right place for it.

What you want is the [`onEnter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback) hook on react router's Route component, which you can use to prevent or redirect before the mounting process has begun.

This was (stupidly) removed from react router in V4, and the community is.... not thrilled about it.  Your use case is the perfect example of why it is a necessary hook, and why I would recommend sticking to V3 of react-router until this hook is brought back to the current version.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I think you need to use this method instead

```
this.history.replace("/")
```